# Angular2 Get error 404 Not found

Tags: angular, angular2-services

this is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Learn AngularJS2 </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- bootstrap -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- fonts -->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:700,400,100,200,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- css link -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <!-- Source files -->
    <script src="js/lib/angular2/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/angular2/system-polyfills.js"></script>

    <script src="js/lib/angular2/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/angular2/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/angular2/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/angular2/angular2.dev.js"></script>

    <script src='https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/http.dev.js'></script>


    <!-- config -->

    <script>
      System.config({
        packages: {
          js: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        }
      });
      System.import('js/boot')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
  </head>
  <!-- Body -->
<body>
<div class="container">

  <httptest>Loading...</httptest>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the http-component

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {httpService} from './http_service';

@Component({
  selector: 'httptest',
  template:`
    <button (click)="onGet()">getData</button>
    <p>Output : {{getData}}</p>
    `,
    providers:[httpService]
})


export class httpComp{

    getData:string;
    constructor(
    private httpService:httpService){}
    onGet(){
    this.httpService.getData()
    .subscribe(
        data => this.getData=JSON.stringfy(data),
        error => alert(error),
        () => console.log("finish")
    );
    }
```

}
and this is my http-service

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular2/core';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()

export class httpService{
constructor (private _http:Http){
    getData(){
        return 
this._http.get('http://localhost:3000/blahblah')
        .map(res => res.json())
        }

    }

    }
```

that is boot.ts

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

import {httpComp} from './http.component';

bootstrap(httpComp);
```

when i run i got these errors

system.src.js:1049 GET http://localhost:8000/@angular2/core 404 (Not Found)
and this error

angular2-polyfills.js:138 Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:8000/@angular2/core(…)

Comment: Which version of angular2 are you using?

Comment: "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.2",

Comment: http://imgur.com/QymsbpI

Comment: http://imgur.com/vwCpCaM

Comment: where is your ngModule file ?

Comment: which one u mean ?

Comment: i solve many things but still have these  plz can help 
http://imgur.com/ov04tv6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@angular/core` notation came with version `2.0.0.rc.0` in `beta` and `alpha` the imports were like `angular2/core`. You have mixed up your imports.

Source: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-rc0-2016-05-02

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {httpService} from './http_service';


@Component({
  selector: 'httptest',
  template:`
    <button (click)="onGet()">getData</button>
    <p>Output : {{getData}}</p>
    `,
    providers:[Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS, httpService]
})


export class httpComp{

    getData:string;
    constructor(
    private httpService:httpService){}
    onGet(){
    this.httpService.getData()
    .subscribe(
        data => this.getData=JSON.stringfy(data),
        error => alert(error),
        () => console.log("finish")
    );
    }
```

Comment: its work now and render the data but i have simple question that it render data in light color like this http://imgur.com/qUVH93z

Comment: @flower your question doesn't include the necessary info for the color issue :/

Comment: so how to make design for it?

Comment: @flower What I would recommend is: start from scratch with latest angular2 version

Comment: but i have something 
i want to display specific object from entire data  but i dont know how do it http://imgur.com/Aehl5wi
@echonax

Comment: @flower your question is about why you are getting 404 response right? If this question is solved, please mark an answer as accepted (http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135826) and if you have other questions please open a new one.

Comment: no its same question i got the data and its 200 but i want to divide the data from function how i can divide 
i pic i send it i wrote comment how i think do it in code but i try it its not work

Comment: @flower ok the question is why you are getting the 404 and I think it is solved.. Because you are saying that you are getting 200 now..

Comment: my question is how can divide the result like this
data =>{this.getDataA=JSON.stringify(data.firstDay),
this.getDataB=JSON.stringify(data.secondDay),
 this.getDataC=JSON.stringify(data.thirdDay)
 }